# missing } after property list

Tags: jquery

I know this is something easy but I just can't see it. Can anyone tell me why I am getting the error "missing } after property list" for the following code:

```
var $newCandleDialog = $('<div></div>')
        .load('/prodash/dash_access.php?urlInit=candles/getCanStatus.php','it='+newData)
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Active Mode: New Candles!',
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Load new candles": function() {
                    $("#canHint").load('/prodash/dash_access.php?urlInit=candles/getcandles.php','q=0&show=05&strength=00');
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );    
                }
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
```

Firebug starts the error with the "Cancel: function" line.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing a `,` before `Cancel:`.

[JSlint](http://www.jslint.com/) is very good at detecting stuff like this.

Comment: I had a similar problem, I had put ':' in place of a ','. JSLint didn't come out and say it, but by looking at all the error lines I found the one that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need a comma between each key/value pair.

```
{
    foo: { },
    bar: { }
}
```

You don't have one between the value for the `buttons` property and the key for the `Cancel` property.